# Python While Loop Results to CSV

Tags: python-2.7

My goal is to capture the stock name (symbol) and the stock price.  I am able to print the results, but I am not sure how to save these results to a text/csv file.  The values in my symbols.txt file are:

```
PIH 
TURN
FLWS
FCCY
SRCE
VNET
TWOU
```

The script I am currently running is:

```
import urllib
import re

symbolfile = open("symbols.txt")

symbolslist = symbolfile.read()

symbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

i=0
while i<len(symbolslist):
    url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/" +symbolslist[i]
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<div id="qwidget_lastsale" class="qwidget-dollar">(.+?)</div>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print "the price of",symbolslist[i]," is " ,price
    i+=1
```

My current output is:

```
the price of PIH  is  ['$7.175']
the price of TURN  is  ['$2.03']
the price of FLWS  is  ['$9.45']
the price of FCCY  is  ['$18']
the price of SRCE  is  ['$50.87']
the price of VNET  is  ['$7.145']
the price of TWOU  is  ['$63.89']
```

My desired output would be a text/csv file with the following values:

```
PIH,$7.175
TURN,$2.03
FLWS,$9.45
FCCY,$18
SRCE,$50.87
VNET,$7.145
TWOU,$63.89
```

Dollar signs, brackets, ect are fine.  I can remove those in another program.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to change the line `print "the price of",symbolslist[i]," is " ,price`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import urllib
import re

symbolfile = open("symbols.txt")

symbolslist = symbolfile.read()

symbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

with open('output.csv', 'w') as output:
    i=0
    while i<len(symbolslist):
        url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/" +symbolslist[i]
        htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
        htmltext = htmlfile.read()
        regex = '<div id="qwidget_lastsale" class="qwidget-dollar">(.+?)</div>'
        pattern = re.compile(regex)
        price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
        output.write('%s,%s\n'%(symbolslist[i], price[0]))
        print "the price of",symbolslist[i]," is " ,price
        i+=1
```

Comment: Is there a way to print these results with a newline for each row?  They appear to be in a single row for now.

Comment: Nevermind.  Figured it out.  output.write('%s,%s'%(symbolslist[i], price[0]+"\n"))

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that, sorry :-)

Comment: I corrected the answer. It is better to place the "\n" inside the initial string

Comment: I'm still a noob.  Thanks!